# Create PyString from c character array without copying

Tags: python, c

I have a large buffer of strings (basically 12GB) from a C app.

I would like to create PyString objects in C for an embedded Python interpreter without copying the strings. Is this possible?

Comment: Anything is possible in computing, given enough time, money and computing resources.  Is that really your question?

Comment: I would like to do this without rewriting PyString.

Comment: @RobertHarvey no that example uses a copy. See https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html#PyString_FromStringAndSize

Comment: Well how are you going to make a Python object and put string data into it without actually copying the data into the object?  Yes, [that function](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html#PyString_FromStringAndSize) is exactly what you need.

Comment: BufferProtocols and NumPy works this way, just give the c pointer. I was hoping there is a way to do this with strings.

Comment: Are you sure that BufferProtocols and NumPy don't copy?

Comment: @Santa do you have an example of calling ctypes from C to an embedded Python interpreter?

Comment: Misread the question. I thought you meant from Python, not C.

Comment: @Santa actually you are right. Use ctypes, I just didn't know you could create a ctypes obj from a pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can't use PyString without a copy, but one can use ctypes. Turns out that `ctypes.c_char_p` works basically like a string. For example with the following C code:

```
static char* names[7] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"};                                      
PyObject *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
pFunc = td_py_get_callable("my_func");
pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
pValue = PyLong_FromSize_t((size_t) names);
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
pValue = PyLong_FromLong(7);
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue);
pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
```

One can then pass the address and the number of character strings With the following python `my_func`:

```
def my_func(names_addr, num_strs):
    type_char_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)
    names = type_char_p.from_address(names_addr)
    for idx in range(num_strs):
        print(names[idx])
```

Of course who really wants to pass around a address and a length in Python. We can put these in a numpy array and pass around then cast if we need to use them:

```
def my_func(name_addr, num_strs):
    type_char_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)
    names = type_char_p.from_address(names_addr)
    // Cast to size_t pointers to be held by numpy
    p = ctypes.cast(names, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t))
    name_addrs = numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(p, shape=(num_strs,))
    // pass to some numpy functions
    my_numpy_fun(name_addrs)
```

The challenge is that evaluating the indices of numpy arrays is only going to give you an address, but the memory is the same as the original c pointer. We can cast back to a `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)` to access values:

```
def my_numpy_func(name_addrs):
    names = name_addrs.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))
    for i in range(len(name_addrs)):
        print names[i]
```

It's not perfect as I can't use things like `numpy.searchsorted` to do a binary search at the numpy level, but it does pass around char* without a copy well enough.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that is possible for the basic reason that Python String objects are *embedded* into the PyObject structure.   In other words, the Python string object is the PyObject_HEAD followed by the bytes of the string.    You would have to have room in memory to put the PyObject_HEAD information around the existing bytes.

Comment: Can I just use numpy.str_? It seems these have problems comparing to other PyStrings though.